# MVC ASP.NET Impersonation enable option missing in IIS Manager 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, kerberos, impersonation

I am trying to overcome the double-hop problem for MVC apps that use Windows Authentication with impersonation on.

While in my IIS manager it is simple enough to use Windows Authentication, the "ASP. Net Impersonation" option for Authentication is missing completely, and hence cannot be enabled.

Does anyone know how to get this option to be available?

Alternatively, a link to a really good guide to overcoming the double-hop problem would be appreciated.  I've searched, some of the sites are blocked by my employer!  I have tried enabling Kerberos, but I wind up using NTLM, because otherwise the app doesn't work at all.   Obviously for an MVC app to be useful, it needs to work on computers other than it's host computer, so I am surprised how hard this is to get working.  Does a "complete guide" to setting this up exist?  I've spent 3 work days Googling this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing it through ad remove windows features in control panel. Individual authentication methods can be added and removed.

Comment: Apparently it is not there either, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you tried to just add it manually to the web.config? I mean the impersonation node: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes; sincere thank you, but this is a double-hop problem that is well beyond that...